# Upgrading phpMyAdmin inside cPanel installation auth_type

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos, cpanel, vps

**System Details:**

- Host: `BlueHost VPS`
- OS: `CENTOS 6.8 x86_64 kvm – server`
- cPanel version: `60.0 (build 28)`
- Current phpMyAdmin version: `4.0.10.14`
- Target phpMyAdmin version: `4.6.5.2`

**Issue Description**:

I am attempting to manually upgrade the version of phpMyAdmin inside of my VPS. cPanel has pushed back upgrading phpMyAdmin several times because they are preserving backwards compatibility with MySQL 5. I do not need this compatibility and would like the bug-fixes and convenience features of the latest 4.6.x branch.

After replacing the installation of phpMyAdmin in `/usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty` I copied in the old `config.inc.php` file from my old installation into the new one and when I attempted to load phpMyAdmin I was given the following error:

`phpMyAdmin - Error
Invalid authentication method set in configuration: cpanel`

After some inspection, it appears that the culprit is this line from `config.inc.php`:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cpanel';`

Which appears to be passing the cPanel credentials to phpMyAdmin for authentication in the old 4.0.x version, but in the new 4.6.x version, this doesn't work anymore.

Despite a lot of Googling and SOing, I can't figure out how to alter this config file to make it so that I can upgrade the installation of phpMyAdmin.

Any insight, resources, or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the 'cpanel' auth_type is, probably some customization done by the cPanel folks that isn't native to phpMyAdmin, which is why your new phpMyAdmin installation doesn't know what to do with it.

I highly suggest letting the cPanel version alone and installing your own phpMyAdmin to a different folder in the web root. You can copy over the `config.inc.php` and make some modifications (for instance, I also suggest using auth_type cookie). I have no idea what might break in cPanel if there are changes to phpMyAdmin, but you should have no problem adding your own version (with a different folder name than the default provided by cPanel). The manual has some more information about the [installation process](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install).

Comment: I appreciate the advice. I was hoping to solve it in a way that would 'upgrade' the version within cPanel... but this is definitely a fine backup plan.

Comment: Well, you certain can try to overwrite the cPanel files in place, but given how they modify the original phpMyAdmin source you might run in to trouble (such as needing to modify the auth_type). It's definitely possible, but might be more hassle than it's worth depending on how important it is for you.